# Laravel Carbon date in format 2017-12-01T16:48:00

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I generate date time in format 2017-12-01T16:48:00 in Laravel 5.8?
When I use this code:

```
Carbon::now()
```

I have result: 2019-08-24 15:07:27.629826 Europe/Warsaw (+02:00)

I need tomorrow's date in format 2019-08-24T15:08:00

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about [Carbon formatting](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting). Also because `Carbon` extends php `DateTime` please read about [date and time formatting in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

As for your question:

```
echo Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); // now
echo Carbon::tomorrow()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); // tomorrow
echo Carbon::now()->addDays($n)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); // n days ahead
```